# CoreAudio AudioFileOpenURL open .avi files

Tags: macos, core-audio

I am trying to open .avi file with AudioFileOpenURL and it fails.
.avi file description: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 29.97 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 44100 Hz)

I am able to open .mp4 .3GP video files.

Question is: is it a codec problem or core audio is not capable to parse audio stream from video files.

I am using Mac OSX 10.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AudioFile / ExtAudioFile APIs won't let you open a movie file and extract the audio component out of the box, unfortunately.

[See here for a list of supported file formats, and what you can do with each](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH7-SW1).